# Is it safe to delete virtuoso.trx?

Tags: virtuoso, transaction-log

I just looked into one of our `Virtuoso` db directories and noticed that `virtuoso.db` is not the biggest file there -- `virtuoso.trx` (transaction log) is.

Assuming that I am happy with the data in `virtuoso.db` and do not anticipate needing to reverse any transactions, is it safe to delete that file and restart (to conserve disk space)?

**RELATED:** [Virtuoso Data Backup & Recovery](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/backup_recovery/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`virtuoso.db` was the active DB immediately following the last `CHECKPOINT`.

`virtuoso.trx` is the transaction log, which holds all changes made since the last `CHECKPOINT` was run.

`virtuoso.db` plus `virtuoso.trx` delivers your current active DB.

You should ***not*** delete the `virtuoso.trx` if you want the `virtuoso.db` to stay as it is.  You should start an iSQL or similar session, and run a `CHECKPOINT()`.  The `.trx` file will be reduced to zero as part of this process.

If you delete this file without running a `CHECKPOINT`, you will lose all that activity -- whether it was `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, or otherwise.

Default configuration has `CheckpointInterval` of 60 minutes -- so a `CHECKPOINT();` will run every 60 minutes, and the transaction log will not grow excessively.

See --

- [6.1.1. Database — Virtuoso Configuration File — `[Parameters]` — `CheckpointInterval=60`](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/dbadm/#ini_parameters_checkpointinterval)
- [9.21. `CHECKPOINT`, `SHUTDOWN` Statement](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/checkpoint/)
- [12.5. Database Shutdown](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/fn_dbev_shutdown/)
- [Tips & Tricks — How can I handle checkpoint condition?](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/chpntset/)
- [Virtuoso Functions Guide & Reference — `checkpoint_interval()` — Configure database checkpointing](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/fn_checkpoint_interval/)

Comment: After the `checkpoint`, you should see that the `.trx` file has dropped to (near) zero bytes, so there should be no reason or need to delete it. If you *do* delete it, it will be recreated when new transactions happen.